# Is there a Monokai syntax highlighting for Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Is there a Monokai syntax highlighting for Visual Studio 2019?

I've tried searching around on Google and I could only find a few that apparently only works on the older versions of Visual Studio.